# Comparative Boxplot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have a `pandas` dataframe similar to the following

```
names   
x     3.5
x     3.7
z     2.8
x     3.4
y     3.25
z     2.9
...
```

And I wish to make a comparative boxplot (three boxplots next to each other for each of `x`, `y`, and `z`. I'm using the `seaborn` package, and I can only get a boxplot for all of the values combined. What am I doing wrong?

```
b = sns.boxplot(data = dat);
```

Comment: Is it a dataframe or a series?

Comment: It's a dataframe. I have other columns @QuangHoang

Comment: So is `names` the column with `x,y,z`, and what is the column name for the numbers?

Comment: See [this example from the docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_boxplot.html). `sns.boxplot(x='names', y='values', data=dat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can draw the [side by side boxplot](https://statsmethods.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/side-by-side-boxplot/) this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO
data = """
names,num
x,3.5
x,3.7
z,2.8
x,3.4
y,3.25
z,2.9
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0)
to_replace = {0:'x', 1:'y', 2:'z'}
df['names'] = df['names'].replace(to_replace=to_replace)
order = ["x", "y", "z"]
sns.boxplot(x="names", y="num", data=df, order=order)
```

Here is the boxplot:

[image]

Refs:

1. [How to use Python Seaborn for Exploratory Data Analysis](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-python-seaborn-for-exploratory-data-analysis-1a4850f48f14)